# Как сделать горизонтальное выравнивание трех блоков?

Tags: html, css

Как выравнивают по горизонтали 3 блока? Думаю `text-align-last: justify` плохой вариант.

Comment: Советую выучить и использывать для таких целей flexbox, плюс сразу будет респонсивность.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что значит "выравнивают по горизонтали"?

Если надо что-то типа такого:

```
[███    ███    ███████]
```

где [] - родительский блок, а ███ - выравниваемые блоки, то родителю поставьте стиль

```
display:flex; //или inline-flex;
justify-content:space-between;
```

и, да, вам в комментарии полезную ссылку дали.